# How to add a screenshot while asking the question

Tags: support, help-center

Whenever I post a question I am unable to add a screen shot of my problem. If the screenshot could be uploaded or added in the question then it would definitely give clarity and clear understanding of the problem. So could anyone tell me where or how to add a screenshot in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Click this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

You'll see this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Follow the instructions on that dialog. You can even just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> or whatever shortcut you use to paste on your machine, and that will work too.

Comment: do we have any rep constraints for adding the image

Comment: I don't remember, probably.

Comment: @user285oo6: There are, yes. Most people that do have enough rep are quite happy to edit posts for those that do not, to replace a link to an image with the image itself.

Comment: @user285oo6: I *think* it is still [10 points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229543/remove-new-user-restrictions-privilege-also-allows-uploading-images) but I need to check this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, it is 10 reputation on Stack Overflow.